# onChange event on Fast UI components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onchange, web-component, fast-ui

I am trying to use Fast UI controls with React and TypeScript. I followed the [React integration instructions](https://www.fast.design/docs/integrations/react), but my `onChange` events are not triggering. What am I missing?

The `onClick` event is working on the checkbox, but onChange is really what I am after.

My code:

```
import { 
  provideFASTDesignSystem, 
  fastCheckbox,
  fastSelect,
  fastOption
} from '@microsoft/fast-components';
import { provideReactWrapper } from '@microsoft/fast-react-wrapper';

const { wrap } = provideReactWrapper(
  React, 
  provideFASTDesignSystem()
);

const FastCheckbox = wrap(fastCheckbox());
const FastSelect = wrap(fastSelect());
const FastOption = wrap(fastOption());
```

```
<FastCheckbox 
  checked={props.properties["fieldsetCheckbox"]}
  onChange={(e: any) => {console.log("onChange");}
/>
```

```
<FastSelect
  value={props.properties["fieldsetCascadingSelect"][0]}
  onchange={(e: any) => {console.log("onchange");}}
>
  <FastOption value="">Select Family...</FastOption>
  {familiesList.map(item => <FastOption value={item.value}>{item.name}</FastOption>)}
</FastSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the FAST `select` element implements all of the functionality of a normal `select` HTML element, then you may find onselect is what you're looking for

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/select_event

Comment: I double checked MDN, the events fired by a normal <select> are `change` and `input`. I still tried `onSelect` and that didn't work, but interestingly `onInput` worked!